# How many states (minimally) for an automaton recognizing the set of words without palindromic subwords on a $k$-letter alphabet?

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata

Let $\Sigma_k = \{0,1,...,k\}$ and let
$NPA_{k}$ be the set of words that do not contain a palindrom (of length $\ge 2$) as a subword.  How many states (minimally) must have an automaton that recognizes the language $NPA_{99}$?

I drew the automaton for $NPA_{2}$ and I proved that it must be minimally  $10$ states (including the initial state and the sink state).
My question is about $NPA_{99}$. How many states (minimally) are needed to recognize this language?  Personally, I think that it is also $10$. To my eye it is sufficient to remember only the two last symbols. It is because of the fact that  if a word is a palindrom then it exists a subword of length $2$ or $3$ which is a palindrom.

(Pay your attention that in this case, a palindrom is a word that has $\ge 2$ symbols).

What about my solution ?

Comment: I actually found 11 states for the minimal DFA of $NPA_2$ (counting the sink state). And my guess for $NPA_k$ is $(k+1)^2 + 2$ (it depends on the alphabet).

Comment: Yes, $11$ (when you including sink). It is minimal - I proved it.  I think of your idea. But where am I wrong ?

Comment: Ok, You are right, I understand now